# how to get owner of all address in solidity?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity

There is a function called ownerOf(uint id) that return the address of this specific id. I want to write a function that gets total supply and pass each total supply id to ownerOf and the return address of the owner of that ID I passed and save in an array.
**here is my code**

and its says: ***ERC721: owner query for nonexistent token***

```
  function GetAllNftOwnerAddress()
    public
    view
    returns (address[] memory) 
{
    uint256 total = totalSupply();
   
    address[] memory tokenIds;
 
    for (uint256 i; i < total; i++) {
       tokenIds[i] = ownerOf(i);
    }
    return tokenIds;
}
```

Comment: so what's the error?

Comment: it says ERC721: owner query for nonexistent token

Comment: the ids are sequential and start from 0?

Comment: yes i also start my loop with (uint256 i=1: I< total ) but output is same

Answer (score 0):

This raised when there's no item with id `i` in the `_owners` array.

This could happen when the `totalSupply()` is different from the length of  `_owners`. Please make sure that the value of `totalSupply` sync with the `_owners`.

E.g.

```
_owners[0] = '0x11'
_owners[1] = '0x22'
_owners[2] = '0x33'
_owners[3] = '0x44'

totalSupply = 4
```

When we do:

```
delete _owners[2]
total -= 1
```

And then try to access:

```
for (uint256 i; i < total; i++) {
   tokenIds[i] = ownerOf(i);
}
```

You'll get an exception when `i == 2` because the `_owner[2] = 0x0`.